# Can $x^y=1$ be regarded as a pair of straight lines?

Tags: conic-sections

For $x> 0$ can $x^y=1$ be regarded as a pair of straight lines $x =1$ and $y =0$. U can get this by taking log on both sides.

Comment: Hi, @Parth Sindhu, Welcome to MSE. Take a [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to the site and see some questions/answers to get a better idea of how to ask a good question. These things will help you in understanding the working of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of. If you mean "Does the solution set of $x^y = 1$ consist of two lines?", then the answer is "yes". As for regarding an equation as the same thing as its solution set...well, no.

Taking log of both sides is a little risky in general, but writing
$$
x^y = e ^ {y \log x}
$$
which is just the definition (sort of ... see below), then makes it possible to write
$$
e^{y \log x } = e^0
$$
and since exponentiation is injective, you get 
$$
y \log x = 0.
$$
whose solutions are just those of $y = 0$ and $\log x = 0$, and the latter has the same solution set as $x = 1$.

---

The only tricky thing here is that $x^y$ is *generally* defined by $e ^ {y \log x}$ for real values of $y$ and for $x > 0$, but for *integer* values of $y$, some negative values of $x$ are allowable as well, so that 
for instance
$$
(-1)^2
$$ 
is well-defined and is $1$, even though $e ^ {2 \log (-1)}$ is not defined, because $\log u$ makes sense only for positive $u$.

So to talk about the equation you wrote, you really need to be very clear about the domain you're considering, and whether any negative values of $x$ are being considered or not. (Even if they are, it turns out that $x^y$ will never be $0$...but for different reasons than the one I gave above.)  Fortunately, in the question itself (although not in the title), you included the restriction that $x > 0$, so my solution works in that case.

Comment: Yes I included x>0 for that reason only. Thanks !